# Cómo sacar valores con split de un archivo txt

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo extraer el valor `<pre>27</pre>` y `<pre>juanito</pre>` con split de un archivo txt conformado con esta estructura:?

```
<CODIGO_TRAMITE>27</CODIGO_TRAMITE>
<NOMBRE_TRAMITE>juanito</NOMBRE_TRAMITE>
```

Este es mi txt completo:

```
    <CODIGO_TRAMITE>27</CODIGO_TRAMITE>

<NOMBRE_TRAMITE>juanito</NOMBRE_TRAMITE>

<CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>12</CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>

<NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>juanita</NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>

<NOMB_DEP>ANTI</NOMB_DEP><NOMB_MUN>BE</NOMB_MUN><CC_PER>705</CC_PER><DIRE_PER>CRA69</DIRE_PER>
```

y con este método del split puedo extraer las 4 primeras lineas:

```
<pre>string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\ruta");


            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] partes = line.Split(new char[] {'<', '>' });
                string valor = partes[2];
               
               
                Console.WriteLine(valor);
                Console.ReadKey();
                
             }</pre>
```

¿Como puedo extraer los valores ANTI, BE, 705 y CRA 69, de la linea 5 ya que no me deja?

---

Este es mi txt completo:
<CODIGO_TRAMITE>27</CODIGO_TRAMITE>

<NOMBRE_TRAMITE>juanito</NOMBRE_TRAMITE>

<CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>12</CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>

<NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>juanita</NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>

<NOMB_DEP>ANTI</NOMB_DEP><NOMB_MUN>BE</NOMB_MUN><CC_PER>705</CC_PER><DIRE_PER>CRA69</DIRE_PER>

y con este método del split puedo extraer las 4 primeras lineas:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\ruta");


            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] partes = line.Split(new char[] {'' });
                string valor = partes[2];
               
               
                Console.WriteLine(valor);
                Console.ReadKey();
                
             }
```

¿Como puedo extraer los valores ANTI, BE, 705 y CRA 69, de la linea 5 ya que no me deja?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola, he intentado convertirlo a xml pero no me ha funcionado, entonces quiero saber como seria bueno extraer la información así sea con split o con otro método

Answer (score 0):

Hola primero tu archivo esta mal, porque es un xml pero no tiene un nodo raíz, primero le tienes que poner uno.

```
<TRAMITE>
      <CODIGO_TRAMITE>27</CODIGO_TRAMITE>
      <NOMBRE_TRAMITE>juanito</NOMBRE_TRAMITE>
      <CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>12</CODIGO_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>
      <NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>juanita</NOMBRE_TIPO_DOCUMENTAL>
      <NOMB_DEP>ANTI</NOMB_DEP>
      <NOMB_MUN>BE</NOMB_MUN>
      <CC_PER>705</CC_PER>
      <DIRE_PER>CRA69</DIRE_PER>
</TRAMITE>
```

Y ahora si lo puedes convertir a Xml y obtener la información

```
string archivo = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\georg\Desktop\a.txt");

    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(archivo);

    var a = doc.SelectSingleNode("*/CODIGO_TRAMITE");
    string codigo = a?.InnerText;

    a = doc.SelectSingleNode("*/NOMBRE_TRAMITE");
    string nombre = a?.InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine($"CODIGO: {codigo} NOMBRE: {nombre}");
```

Comment: Hola, el archivo es un txt pero la información viene desordenada, tu ejemplo que estas mostrando está ordenado y cuando la trato de convertir en xml los nodos se convierten en string y no los toma como nodos de xml

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione y lo hice con

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {""};

string[] resul;

resul = line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);